# How to enter formatted template in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an online letter template that I want to display ask text in my reactApp

My email is formatted with paragraphs and bold headings. How can I integrate the same formatting into React without having to use bruteforce and including a lot of tags.

I tried using a template literal to preserve the formatting but it does not work.

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joseph stated in the comments, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render a string of HTML.

Example: [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dangerously-set-inner-html-59u0q)

```
export default function App() {
  const htmlString = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
  return (
    <>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, it's important to be aware of the security risks as the documentation states:

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml